# Adding Values from the Database to the Comboboxes

Tags: c#, sql, database, ssms

So I already connected my database from the form and I kinda wanna know how would I add the data of the `Strand_Name` and `Status_Name` to the respective ComboBoxes they belong. I've been messing up with the `Add.Items` thing and I don't know which code am I going to use and what `private void` should I put the code. Any suggestions?

[image: screencap of my form]

Comment: You can use databinding to map a table to a CBO.  The user will see the name, your code can get the ID using `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`.  Many hundreds of posts here showing how

Comment: Are you creating a WinForms or WPF application? And is this your homework?

Comment: It is a WPF Application. No, this is an enrollment database for the school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //Try My code.
    // Call it On form load or IntializeComponent()

    private void GetStrand()
      {//depending on your database bind data like..
         string query="select strand_id,strand_name from strand ";
         using(MysqlConnection con =new MysqlConnection(//your connection string here)
         {
           con.open();
           using(MysqlCommand cmd = new MysqlCommand(query,con)
          {
          MysqlDataReader reader =cmd.ExecuteReader();
          while(reader.read())
          {
           string _strand= reader.GetString("strand_name");
           cbostrand.Items.Add(_strand);

           }
           }
          }

       }
```